# Is this a bug that I bumped into?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I recently asked [this question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/47172/19902), which featured [another question that I asked](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/51543/19902) as linked; but they are not linked at all. The only link is that I asked the questions in question.
Did I bump into a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a bug. The list of "linked" questions in the sidebar does not only contain links from this *question to* the other ones, but also links from any *of the comments or answers* to any other questions or answers *and* links from those questions or their comments and answers *to* this question or its answers. It basically tracks **all direct connections between both question pages**.

In that specific case, [an answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/51546/49) to the second question contained a link to [an answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/47173/49) from the first question. Therefore both questions appear in each others' linked questions lists.

Comment: Oh, it seems I have missed this. This, and my lack of knowledge of what you just said. Thanks.